# Wikidata query to get country synonyms but not flag symbols

Tags: regex, database, unicode, sparql, wikidata

I am using the following query to get a list of ISO countries with their details:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?code  ?wikipedia ?countryAltLabel
WHERE
{
  ?country wdt:P297 ?code .
  OPTIONAL {     
                    ?wikipedia schema:about ?country .
                    ?wikipedia schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
                    } .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```

The results I am getting look like this:[image]

Is there any way to remove flag symbols from the list of CountryAltLabels?

Comment: https://w.wiki/XWh

Comment: @StanislavKralin You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points:

1. Those flags are pairs of symbols from U+1F1E6—U+1F1FF, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62996276/7879193) by Tom Morris.
2. The label service should be used in the [manual mode](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service).
3. A particular query execution order should be forced (via `hint:Query hint:optimizer "None"`).

```sql
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?code ?wikipedia ?countryAltLabel ?alt {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" . 
  ?country wdt:P297 ?code
  OPTIONAL { ?wikipedia schema:about ?country ; schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?country skos:altLabel ?countryAltLabel ; rdfs:label ?countryLabel         
  } 
  BIND ( REPLACE(?countryAltLabel, "[-]{2}, |, ?[-]{2}", "") AS ?alt )
}
```

https://w.wiki/Xcv

Note that these  and  are not regular  capital letters. One could write `[\\x{1f1e6}-\\x{1f1ff}]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a little strange that their included as alt labels, but they should be relatively easily to filter out from the results. They will always be exactly two characters from RGI alphabet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol

Comment: but how do I put a filter query?

Comment: maybe you could try converting them to lowercase and get the results.